# UIImageView in UIButton is not rendered properly when selected in Simulator

Tags: swift, uiimageview, storyboard

This is how it looks in storyboard:

[image]

... and after selected:

[image]

This is my subclass:

```
@IBDesignable class WLButton: UIButton {

    override var selected: Bool {

        didSet {

            backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.scooter() : UIColor.clearColor()
            imageView?.tintColor = selected ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.grayColor()
            imageView?.image = imageView?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is output in Simulator when selected:

[image]

**Why imageView is not rendered as it should?**

Answer (score 0):

Change last 2 lines to:

```
setImage(imageView?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```